# QGIS Has Rendering Error on JP2000 Raster. Works in ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, jpeg-2000

I've got a large .jp2 raster file that was created using 'Mosaic to New Raster' in ArcGIS. I'm trying to open it in QGIS 2.8.6 (I've tried 2.8.14 as well) and am getting a vertical line that won't render properly. The problem occurs at all zoom levels.

Has anyone else had this issue? Is there a quick fix or is this just a bug in the ecw/jp2 raster plugin?

Edit: Here's what gdalinfo shows:

```
F:\>gdalinfo wor_wgs.jp2
Driver: JP2ECW/ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.0)
Files: wor_wgs.jp2
       wor_wgs.jp2.aux.xml
Size is 145095, 107689
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-72.016980560378059,42.486752002435146)
Pixel Size = (0.000003234921015,-0.000003234921015)
Metadata:
  COLORSPACE=MULTIBAND
  COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET=0
  Corder=PCRL
  VERSION=1
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -72.0169806,  42.4867520) ( 72d 1' 1.13"W, 42d29'12.31"N)
Lower Left  ( -72.0169806,  42.1383866) ( 72d 1' 1.13"W, 42d 8'18.19"N)
Upper Right ( -71.5476097,  42.4867520) ( 71d32'51.39"W, 42d29'12.31"N)
Lower Right ( -71.5476097,  42.1383866) ( 71d32'51.39"W, 42d 8'18.19"N)
Center      ( -71.7822951,  42.3125693) ( 71d46'56.26"W, 42d18'45.25"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=55.220, StdDev=56.686
  NoData Value=256
  Overviews: 72547x53844, 36273x26922, 18136x13461, 9068x6730, 4534x3365, 2267x1
682, 1133x841, 566x420, 283x210
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=3213.34265916292,3031.77726231577,2726.40295849355,31
29.54838322411
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=55.220242282501
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=56.686353376831
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JP2000
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=55.180, StdDev=54.204
  NoData Value=256
  Overviews: 72547x53844, 36273x26922, 18136x13461, 9068x6730, 4534x3365, 2267x1
682, 1133x841, 566x420, 283x210
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=3031.77726231577,2938.03869526213,2628.71829197938,31
15.81640621639
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=55.180213092815
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=54.203677875787
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JP2000
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=51.535, StdDev=49.223
  NoData Value=256
  Overviews: 72547x53844, 36273x26922, 18136x13461, 9068x6730, 4534x3365, 2267x1
682, 1133x841, 566x420, 283x210
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=2726.40295849355,2628.71829197938,2422.87224936175,27
24.010779609
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=51.535068822992
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=49.222680233422
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JP2000
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=64.895, StdDev=64.197
  NoData Value=256
  Overviews: 72547x53844, 36273x26922, 18136x13461, 9068x6730, 4534x3365, 2267x1
682, 1133x841, 566x420, 283x210
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=3129.54838322411,3115.81640621639,2724.010779609,4121
.28152183373
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=64.894546059985
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=64.197208053261
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JP2000
```

[image: Renders in ArcMap]

[image: Error is QGIS]

Comment: Almost impossible to say without having an access to your image. You can, however, check with `gdalinfo --formats` which JPEG2000 drivers you have in your GDAL version (there are 5 alternatives, see http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg2000.html) and they do not behave similarly. And there are also differences between the versions of the ECW/JPEG2000 SDK.

Comment: The JP2ECW/ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.0) is pretty good one. There may be something special in your image. Which platform do you have? Perhaps you can try how the kdu_show viewer deals with your image http://kakadusoftware.com/downloads/.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating to the latest ecwjp2 5.2 release. 5.0 is a few years old now and jp2 has had many fixes applied

Comment: Has this specific issue been addressed with a new release or are you just suggesting an upgrade? Please edit your answer to include more information.